# Custom path for syslog socket

Tags: kernel, syslog

I am trying to use a custom path for `syslogd` socket by using `-p` option as below

```
syslogd -p /tmp/my_path
```

Even though I see the socket file is getting created correctly, the logging is not happening to syslog storage (even with explicit rules in /etc/syslog.conf)

Do I need any extra changes in syslog.conf to send logs to alternative socket /tmp/my_path which is used instead of /dev/log ?

Comment: my first intuition is that your `syslogd` is not actually used for syslog logging, because `journald` already does that (at least that's what's happening on most modern linuxes). Can you verify your system isn't actually using journald? What linux distro (in which version) is this?

Comment: My system is still using the legacy syslogd which creates a socket file and does not use systemd implementation that creates a softlink to journal.

Comment: yeah but that's the point: No other program will use your socket if you don't link /dev/lock to it! But if you modified your software to do that, then you'd be fine.

Comment: Sure..any other option other than creating the custom location as softlink to /dev/log?

Can I set/pass some data to syslog() call or edit syslog.conf to use this new path?

Comment: you can't, libc / syslog uses /dev/log. syslog.conf is a syslogd thing, not something the clients worry about.

Comment: Is it possible you're trying to implement something like logging categories / filtering for this? That you'd do differently! (are you sure you want to do this using syslogd instead of systemd journald? This really feels awkward; the complexity of filtering in `syslogd` is much higher than it is with `journalct`.

Comment: Sure..thanks, will explore

Comment: The more I think about it, the more I think you'll like the journald "Journal Namespaces" concept: you can run multiple journald instances in parallel, and assign services to these, so that their logs only end up being processed by "their" specific journald. All it takes is using the `systemd-journald@.service` service :)

Comment: Thank you! I will explore on this.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is totally nonsensical.

Daemons usually log by calling the `syslog(3)` function from the C library, which works by sending a message to the **hardwired** `/dev/log` unix domain socket. Forcing `syslogd` to use some random path for that socket is just like not running `syslogd` at all.

Note: this is also true of systemd. Systemd wants to force everybody to stop using `syslog(3)`, and log error messages by just writing to the stderr (which was redirected in advance by systemd), but it still implements `/dev/log` for compatibility.